# Short black screen after windows 7 boots

Tags: windows-7, boot

When I turn on my laptop, it's a Lenovo [W520](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/system_data/w520_tech_specs.pdf), everything seems to work just fine but after the Windows logo and before the Desktop loads I get a black screen for about 30 seconds, and after that the desktop loads and everything is ok. I can only see the cursor on the black screen before the desktop loads. It does not affect anything, it is just a bit annoying that it boots into windows but does not load the desktop.

I can even take a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3H2Q.png) during this 30 second window of time.
I have uploaded the zipped boot trace file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9z08l2q2ydelej/Boot%20Trace.rar)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's a really convincing screenshot :)

Comment: Yes, I'm not being rude but I really had a good giggle at the screen shot. As if I didn't know what a black screen looked like  :)

Comment: Wasn't there a hotfix for this?

Comment: capture a xbootmgr trace, zip and upload it. http://www.cluberti.com/blog/2011/07/22/using-xbootmgr-to-trace-boot-shutdown-and-reboot-performance-issues/

Comment: @DaveRook I really did not know if I should attach it or not. :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Dell XPS M1730 and fixed it by reinstalling Windows.
Things you should check before reinstalling:

- Eventlog (open eventvwr.msc) and take a look at all the items within the last 5 minutes.
- Take a look at your profile: is there a shitload of stuff on your desktop? Is it mounting network drives?
- Take a look at your autostart in the msconfig.exe (as suggested by Dave Rook)
- Update your drivers, applications, windows and everything else.
- Follow this link, it contains information on how to measure boot time and how to disable things which could slow it down: http://itexpertvoice.com/home/what%E2%80%99s-taking-so-long-how-to-fight-slow-startup-times-in-windows-7/
- If nothing works and it really drives you crazy, try reinstalling your system.

Comment: This is pretty thorough, +1

Comment: @Vanadis - These are all good suggestions.  I would also agree that the problem in the screenshot is either caused by a very slow process that is started during the boot process or you have some really old display drivers.  I would try to make sure to disable every single startup process possible and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried the above steps but I was not able to find the problem.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check out what programs are loading via MSCONFIG, disable them and see if the issue persists. If it solves it,  you have your problem and will have to re-enable the programs one at a time until you find the culprit.

Or, you need to check out the Scheduled Tasks and see if any program is executing on load.

Lastly, if you can get to task manager during this time, then see what is running as this may give you the best indication.